# Reload PHP include without innerHTML

Tags: php, dynamic, refresh, chat

When someone on my Minecraft server sends a chat message, a plugin sends that message to a listener.php file, which enters the info into a Mysql database. I am trying to display it in real time (well, as close as possible) in the admin panel I am building for the website. While using .load works as far as getting the content on the page, it breaks the jquery-operated scrollbars I have on the chatbox, making it where you can't scroll down through the posts. This is because it has to have enough 's to warrant the need for scrolling before the scrollbar will appear, but with the .load, the only  present is the  that the contents of chat.php are being loaded into. the only way I can get the chat to work is including the chat.php with a php include, with chat.php looking like:

```
<?php


echo "<div class='block messages scrollBox'><div class='scroll' style='height: 320px;'> ";

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","bduser","pass","dbase");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM server_chat ORDER BY date DESC , time DESC LIMIT 15");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

$user = $row['user'];
$message = $row['message'];
$date = $row['date'];
$time = $row['time'];


echo "<div class='item clearfix'><div class='image'><a href='#'><img src='../face.php?u=$user'         class='img-polaroid' /></a></div><div class='info'><a class='name' href='#'>$user</a><p>$message</p>    <span>$time $date</span></div></div>";



}

mysqli_close($con);

echo "</div></div>";
?>
```

How do I keep the above format for displaying the contents of the chat table on my database, but update it every 5 seconds or so? Is there a way to automatically re-query the database? While code snippets help, I in the learning process, either pointing me in the right direction via q link to what method to use, or telling me what needs to be done and leaving the coding up to me would help much more in the long run. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE: copy that php code too, i change it**

Try this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var interval = setInterval(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'chat_reload.php',
                        success: function(data) {
                            $('#toreload').html(data);
                        }
                    });
                }, 1000);
            });        
</script>



<?php


echo "<div class='block messages scrollBox'><div class='scroll' style='height: 320px;'><div id='toreload'> ";

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","bduser","pass","dbase");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM server_chat ORDER BY date DESC , time DESC LIMIT 15");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

$user = $row['user'];
$message = $row['message'];
$date = $row['date'];
$time = $row['time'];


echo "<div class='item clearfix'><div class='image'><a href='#'><img src='../face.php?u=$user'         class='img-polaroid' /></a></div><div class='info'><a class='name' href='#'>$user</a><p>$message</p>    <span>$time $date</span></div></div>";



}

mysqli_close($con);

echo "</div></div></div>";
?>
```

AND:
There in folder, where is this PHP code make new file with name **chat_reload.php** and put there this code:

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","bduser","pass","dbase");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM server_chat ORDER BY date DESC , time DESC LIMIT 15");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $user = $row['user'];
    $message = $row['message'];
    $date = $row['date'];
    $time = $row['time'];


    echo "<div class='item clearfix'><div class='image'><a href='#'><img src='../face.php?u=$user'         class='img-polaroid' /></a></div><div class='info'><a class='name' href='#'>$user</a><p>$message</p>    <span>$time $date</span></div></div>";



    }

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: It reload chat every 1 second (1000 miliseecond...) if you want 5 secont, that 1000 inScript, change to 5000.